# Сгенерировать случайные числа с ограничениями в Python

Tags: python, случайные-числа, pandas, numpy, scipy

Есть система из множества неравенств и одного уравнения вида:

```
x+y>= 60

x<=20

y<=50

x+y+z == 100
```

Задача стоит сгенерировать множество случайных чисел, удовлетворяющих данным ограничениям. Я пытался решить проблему фиксацией одной переменной на основе ограничений (при этом система задается в матричном виде, где 1 в последнем столбце значит >=, 2 <=, 3 ==):

```
m1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
   [[  1,   1,   0,  60,   1],
   [1, 0,   0,  20,   2],
   [1,  1,   1, 100,   3]]
  ))

vars = []

num_var = m1.shape[1] - 2
for i in range(num_var):
 if m1.shape[1] == 3:
    x = 100 - sum(vars)
 else: 
    max = (m1[(m1.iloc[:,0]!=0)&((m1.iloc[:,-1]==2)|
    (m1.iloc[:,-1]==3))]).iloc[:,-2]
    max = max.min()
    min = (m1[(m1.iloc[:,0]!=0)&(m1.iloc[:,-1]==1)&
    ((m1.iloc[:,1:-2]==0).sum(axis = 
    1)==m1.iloc[:,1:-2].shape[1])].iloc[:,-2])
    min = min.max()
    if math.isnan(min):
        min = 0.01
    x = np.random.uniform(min, max)
    m1.iloc[:,-2] = m1.iloc[:,-2] - m1.iloc[:,0] * x 
    m1 = m1.iloc[:,1:]
    vars.append(x)
```

С простой системой будто бы работает, но при усложнении вообще перестает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше решить данную проблему.

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет что-то из этой статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/330648/

Answer (score 0):

Из уравнения следует, что x не может быть меньше 10, а y не может быть меньше 40. Поэтому предлагаю такое решение.

```
import random
result = []
for i in range(1000):
    x = random.uniform(10, 20)
    y = random.uniform(40, 50)
    if x + y >=60:
        z = 100 - x - y
        result.append((x,y,z))
    else:
        continue
```